# JSON request for .each not working in IE7 but works fine on other browers

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, internet-explorer-7

Hello I have a simple getJSON call that I have implemented on my site. It works fine however IE7 seems to output and error. Can anyone suggest me what's going on?

```
    var output = '';
    var fullurl = 'myurl'
    $.getJSON(fullurl, function(json) {

    $.each(json, function(i,d) {
        output = '<span style="font-size:11px;"><b>Name :</b> '+d.Name+'</span><br>';
        output += '<span style="font-size:11px;"><b>Date :</b> '+d.Date+'</span><br><br>';
        output += '<span style="font-size:11px;"><b>Description :</b> '+d.Description+'</span><br>'; 
    }); 
    $('#description').append(output);
```

There are two errors poping up

```
 Error: Object doesn't support this property or method
 Error: Expected identifier, string or number
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: and what error is that

Comment: Where is `output` defined?

Comment: @RocketHazmat on top of full url, I'll update code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to solve these kinds of problems is to put your copy of IE into IE7 emulation and then use F12 to fire up the debugger.  You can then set a breakpoint on the `$.each()` line and examine the results of your JSON call.  You can then further set a breakpoint inside the `.each()` iteration and step through each until you encounter the error and can see what data/code is causing the error.  The IE console may also tell you exactly which line of code is causing the error.

If you want us to guess what might be wrong, here are my guesses:

1. If you are not getting any JSON data, then there is nothing to run `.each()` on and `input` is never initialized.  When you then try to do `$('#description').append(output);`, `output` may be undefined which causes an error.
2. In addition, `input` should be declared as a local variable.
3. In addition, your current code is NOT accumulating the `input` values from all iterations of the loop - it's just getting the last iteration.  I don't know exactly what your intent is, but you probably want to initialize `input` outside the loop and use `+=` inside the loop for all three lines.  This will accumulate, rather than replace for each loop.

Here's code that incorporates those changes:

```
var fullurl = 'myurl';
$.getJSON(fullurl, function(json) {
    var output = "";
    $.each(json, function(i,d) {
        output += '<span style="font-size:11px;"><b>Name :</b> '+d.Name+'</span><br>';
        output += '<span style="font-size:11px;"><b>Date :</b> '+d.Date+'</span><br><br>';
        output += '<span style="font-size:11px;"><b>Description :</b> '+d.Description+'</span><br>'; 
    }); 
    $('#description').append(output);
});
```

Comment: fixed!, Thank you. can you explain me to what you me by IE7 Emulation?

Comment: If you bring up the IE debug window with F12, that window has a menu for browser mode where you can select IE7.

Comment: @BaconJuice It is only present in IE8+ If you were doing your debugging in, IE9 for example, you could make it render the page in IE7 mode to test IE7 without having to have IE7 installed while giving you a powerful debugger to help find problems.

Comment: @BaconJuice - in older versions of IE, the debugger has to be separately installed.  In newer versions, it's automatically available.